# pip install in Cygwin cannot find file error

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin, pip, anaconda, parallels

I am on a Mac OS El Capitan, running a Windows 10 64-bit VM inside Parallels. I have Cygwin installed and Anaconda3. I would like to install two packages (pyrsistent and rpy2) using pip. Both of them throw an error "error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" without specifying the file it can't find.

Here's the output:

```
$ pip install pyrsistent
Collecting pyrsistent
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.11.9.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyrsistent)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyrsistent
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyrsistent
  Complete output from command C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\pip-build-sqcinj9m\\pyrsistent\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\cygwin64\tmp\tmpn25raothpip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  copying _pyrsistent_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_checked_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_field_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_immutable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_pbag.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_pclass.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_pdeque.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_plist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_pmap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_precord.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_pset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_pvector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\_transformations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  copying pyrsistent\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
  running build_ext
  building 'pvectorc' extension
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyrsistent
Failed to build pyrsistent
Installing collected packages: pyrsistent
  Running setup.py install for pyrsistent
    Complete output from command C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\pip-build-sqcinj9m\\pyrsistent\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-_wbdiief-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'pvectorc' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\pip-build-sqcinj9m\\pyrsistent\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-_wbdiief-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-build-sqcinj9m\pyrsistent
```

Both python3 and pip are in the path:

```
$ which pip
/cygdrive/c/Anaconda3/Scripts/pip

$ which python
/cygdrive/c/Anaconda3/python
```

The error is identical when trying to install rpy2 so it's not something particular to the package I'm trying to install. Does anyone have ideas of the problem or ideas for troubleshooting? I've tried debugging into the install.py but the code throwing the error is in C. I've tried doing the install in verbose mode, but it still doesn't say what file it cannot find in that case.
(and if you're wondering why I haven't used conda, it's because it doesn't install pyrsistent, and for the rpy2 install, it insists on linking it to its own install of R, and even when specifying my own install, something doesn't link correctly. I've already been down that road and would like to stick to pip).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for anyone who is stuck installing python packages on Windows. There are several sites that have Windows binaries for python packages. I was able to find a binary for rpy2 [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) but there are several other sites too, if you just google something like "python Windows binaries". Then I did:

```
pip install rpy2-2.7.4-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

pyrsistent was not in that website or any of several other binaries websites I found. But someone else on my dev team sent me the /pyrsistent directory inside his Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages directory and after copying it to the same directory on my machine, I was able to import pyrsistent as well.

It's not pretty, but it worked.